# How to setup middle button action in IntelliPoint?

Tags: windows-8, mouse, wireless-mouse, intellimouse

I have Microsoft Wireless Mouse 5000 and it's Control Panel applet allows to setup: (1) left button, (2) right button, (3) wheel, (4) second left button (tiny one) and (5) second right button (tiny one).

But my mouse also accept click performed by the wheel.

Where are setup for this action?

My OS is Win 8.